Gnome RDP Stop accepting connection after X hours
I'm a new user of linux. I wanted linux to make a very small pc live again and be a distant server... End of the story!  :P
As the title say, the gnome RDP server stop working after a certain amount of time. I explain the timeline to this. Let's take for example that I just booted my system. I can connect via RDP with no problem. I can log out and come back to it say 20-30 minutes later. BUT if I leave the system for say the night, the next morning it is impossible for me to connect again by RDP. The connection is refused. I don't know after how long the RDP server stops wanting to respond but let's say it's between 1 hour and 7 hours. However, all other protocols work as much after startup as after a night (http, FTP, SSH). Everything(except gnome RDP) work well also from distant pc/android.
As i'm new to Linux, figuring what it could be is really hard!
echo from 'sudo lsof -i:3389' and 'systemctl --user status gnome-remote-desktop.service'
COMMAND   PID                 USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
gnome-rem 948 gnome-remote-desktop   14u  IPv6  15523      0t0  TCP *:ms-wbt-server (LISTEN)
● gnome-remote-desktop.service - GNOME Remote Desktop
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/gnome-remote-desktop.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-10-18 14:01:37 EDT; 76ms ago
   Main PID: 50356 (gnome-remote-de)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 18844)
     Memory: 3.2M (peak: 3.8M)
        CPU: 20ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/gnome-remote-desktop.service
             └─50356 /usr/libexec/gnome-remote-desktop-daemon

Oct 18 14:01:37 frank systemd[49964]: Starting gnome-remote-desktop.service - GNOME Remote Desktop...
Oct 18 14:01:37 frank systemd[49964]: Started gnome-remote-desktop.service - GNOME Remote Desktop.
francois@frank:~$

Can someone direct me on what is not working, where to look, what to do?
Thank you very much!
